# Mixing Angular 6+ single page app with static HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

Here is the problem, that for my surprise, I can't find answer to.

I'm developing a web site that has static HTML pages and Angular 6 single page app.

I need my landing page index.html to be a regular static HTML/CSS page. On this page I want to have regular  links to some other static HTML pages and one link to my Angular single page application. So basically I want Angular app to be just one of the pages of my otherwise static HTML site. Right now I can reference regular static pages from Angular app. I just need to put those static pages to Assets folder or to any other folder that I specify in Assets section in angular.json. While I can't find a way to make landing index.html just a regular static page.

If I configure "index" as shown bellow - it always redirects me to main.html (my Angular app landing page) - even if I type  http://localhost:4200/index.html in the browser - it redirects me to Angular app anyway.

```
"options": {
        ...
        "index": "src/main.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use a regular static page?

Comment: @jetset I want my landing page to be static and to have links to my other static pages - so google and other search engines could easily discover my entire site content. Putting Angular app as the first landing page can hide you entire site content from search crawlers. Also I simply don't need entire site to be single page application.

Comment: Gotcha! Angular has a solution for this, it's called Angular Universal and it solves the exact problems you have. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: @jetset yeah, I heard about it - the problem with angular universal and server side rendering is that it requires server side processing. I have more or less static site. And I host it using static hosting (because you can get it for free) - no server side code allowed. And I use Angular app just to make a few pages of my site more dynamic. So I don't need my entire site to be Angular app.

Comment: Definitely an interesting problem, I get where you are coming from. There's no best practice that I'm aware of to accomplish what you want statically. The reason I believe this is so difficult is because when you host a SPA using static hosting, you need to route all requests to the index.html, including 404's. That allows angular to take over the routing. Trying to build a mix between the two isn't a supported use case so anything will be a nasty hack. I wish I could be of more help, good luck on your search!

Comment: @jetset Thanks anyway! I think I can simply add one hidden link to the site map somewhere inside index.html of my Angular app - it should be enough for google bots to discover my entire site content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181028/discussion-between-jetset-and-elya-s).